# Android Snackbar covering the control buttons in Google Pixel

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-snackbar

The Snackbar covers the control buttons of the Google Pixel device. The device is running Nougat and the screenshot illustrates the issue:

[image]

This is happening due to the buttons being virtual. What changes are required to avoid this issue in devices where the control buttons are virtual?

**Code:**

```
Snackbar.make(MainActivity.this.getWindow().getDecorView(), getString(R.string.incorrect_details), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Try to use in the first parameter findViewById(android.R.id.content)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use as the first parameter android.R.id.content

```
 Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), getString(R.string.incorrect_details), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```